# Full-page graphic within multicol

Tags: floats, multicol

A full-page graphic can be included in an ordinary single-column document using `\begin{figure*}[t!] ... \end{figure*}` (regardless of overfull boxes which can be avoided).

But that obviously fails withinin a `multicol`-environment: There is no problem, when the included image leaves place for some additional text, but when the image requires the entire `\textheight`, the image is not included at the desired position but is shifted down after the end of the two-column text.

Changing `\topfraction` etc. has no influence on that behavior.

Is there a solution for that behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to realize that figure* always places a float always on a later page, never on the current one. Furthermore, `[!t]`is not enough, the `!` is only relevant when a float is tried for the current page, it is ignored by LaTeX otherwise. Bit surprising, but not an area that I would like to alter.
Anyway, if you use `[!tp]` it works, both in single column and in multicols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
 \vrule height \textheight width 1pt
 \caption{big figure}
\end{figure*}

\kant[2-10]

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
\kant[1]

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
 \vrule height \textheight width 1pt
 \caption{big figure}
\end{figure*}

\kant[2-20]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what You want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image-a.png}
  \caption{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[3-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: more natural to use `begin{figure}[h]` as  `figure*`  doesn't support `h` (it just does here as it is a single column document so `figure*` is aliased to `figure`)